# Oracle WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

i have two SQL  statements as shown below :

```
SELECT AUDIT_OPTION, SUCCESS, FAILURE
FROM DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS
WHERE AUDIT_OPTION='USER'
AND USER_NAME IS NULL
AND PROXY_NAME IS NULL
AND SUCCESS = 'BY ACCESS'
AND FAILURE = 'BY ACCESS';
```

and

```
SELECT AUDIT_OPTION, SUCCESS, FAILURE
FROM DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS
WHERE AUDIT_OPTION='ALTER USER'
AND USER_NAME IS NULL
AND PROXY_NAME IS NULL
AND SUCCESS = 'BY ACCESS'
AND FAILURE = 'BY ACCESS';
```

As you can see only the WHERE Clause value changes. My question is how can i mix these two statements so i can both results at once

Thank you

Comment: You haven't come across `OR`, `IN` or `uNION [ALL]`?

Comment: Im a bit new to Oracle, Im actually trying to automatize an auditing script for oracle but im not so familiar with the syntax

Comment: Just  suggestion - if you're not familiar with the syntax then do a simple online tutorial and browse the Oracle documentation related to what you want to do. Boolean operations like AND, OR and NOT are fundamental to just about any coding - learn about them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i am doing it in parallel. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to `UNION (ALL)` those two `SELECT`s, or modify `AUDIT_OPTION` and include both options, such as

```
SELECT audit_option, success, failure
  FROM dba_stmt_audit_opts
 WHERE     audit_option IN ('USER', 'ALTER USER')
       AND user_name IS NULL
       AND proxy_name IS NULL
       AND success = 'BY ACCESS'
       AND failure = 'BY ACCESS';
```

Or, previously mentioned `UNION`:

```
SELECT audit_option, success, failure
  FROM dba_stmt_audit_opts
 WHERE     audit_option = 'USER'
       AND user_name IS NULL
       AND proxy_name IS NULL
       AND success = 'BY ACCESS'
       AND failure = 'BY ACCESS'
UNION ALL
SELECT audit_option, success, failure
  FROM dba_stmt_audit_opts
 WHERE     audit_option = 'ALTER USER'
       AND user_name IS NULL
       AND proxy_name IS NULL
       AND success = 'BY ACCESS'
       AND failure = 'BY ACCESS';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.This would give me both results right ? and both statements would be independent from each other ?

Comment: You're welcome. Both queries I posted should return the same result.